# Skip.footer.line.count not working for files greater than 256MB

Tags: hive

I have multiple flat files with are fixed width. Files record count comes in trailer record prefixed with '!'

I am storing this data in hive staging tables which are in text file format and skipping trailer record using `skip.footer.line.count` given as `1`.

Staging tables have just 1 column called `data_table_name` and entire record from respective flat file is stored here.

Target tables are in parquet format and gets populated using substring of the `data_table_name` column from staging table into multiple columns of target table.

Whenever the file size is more than 256 MB, skip trailer is not working properly and instead a record from the middle of the file is getting skipped.

I found the same issue discussed in the below link but do not know what is the solution.Could someone please suggest how to fix it.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/HIVE-15359

Answer (score 0):

1. Filter table using `where data_table_name !='data_table_name'`
2. Try `set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat;`

Comment: Yeah, that is a workaround I have thought of to filter the table.But can I avoid it altogether.

Comment: @SurbhiJain Does it reproduce with HiveInputFormat ?

Comment: Yeah even with the given hive format, it reproduces